# face recognition using fisher algorithm

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on face recognition using openCV.I could able to save the collected face images for training in ram memory hence i cant retrieve those images for later use.
How to save the collected face images in secondary memory and retrieve it?

Comment: [r.a. fisher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i might misunderstand your question, but -

apart from reloading the images and retrain the facerecognition every time, you can save the trained recognition model to an xml/yaml file. you would only train it *once* using the images:

```
vector<Mat> train_imgs;
Mat train_labels;
facerec->train( train_imgs, labels );

// save to disk:
facerec->save( "faces_trained.xml" );

int label = facerec->predict( image );
```

and the next time, you could skip the images and the training, and  load the xml instead:

```
// load from disk:
facerec->load( "faces_trained.xml" );

int label = facerec->predict( image );
```

reading a bit [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html) might not hurt, too ;)